# Were lay people ever forbidden to read the Bible in the Christian world?

Tags: christianity, bible, religious-history

I'm interested in all the historical accounts, if any, where the Bible was forbidden/censured  to be read, by order of secular powers in the Christian world, i.e. mainly Roman Empire or the Byzantine Empire.
I vaguely know of two instances, neither of which I can confirm if true. One regarding [Code of Justinian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Justinian), where supposedly Emperor Justinian only allowed the clergy to read the Bible (again I'd like to confirm this), second was of King Henry VIII of England, before the Reformation, persecuting the Tyndale translation.

Comment: Forbidding reading the Bible in the allowed language (Hebrew, Greek, Latin) and forbidding its translations into vernaculars are different things. Lay Roman people could easily read it in Latin, while lay Englishmen couldn't.

Comment: For most of history it wasn't necessary to "forbid" people to read a document; they couldn't read, and didn't have a copy.  Kind of like forbidding people to violate the third law of thermodynamics.  IIRC the Catholic church discouraged lay education into the 17th century.  This is a rich area for research, but I'm drawing a blank on better keywords.  Vernacular translations?  someone can do better than that. I thought this was one of the Hussite /Wycliff points of contention.  Also implied in clerical privilege (anyone who could recite the Bible was a cleric...)

Comment: @YellowSky Thanks. I'm interested in any of those two, so the distinction is not relevant for my purposes.

Comment: Fun fact, many Protestant churches in the USA (*especially* high-church types like Episcopalian) have a ceremonial public copy of the scriptures in English somewhere off in the corner that anyone can go up and read at their pleasure. It's not really intended for public use anymore (since most of the target audience would already have their own copy), but it serves as a public statement that the scriptures are an open book to anyone who cares to inquire.

Comment: This needs detail & clarity: when, where, which bible, etc. Eg. would it count here: 'being in *suspect possession* of a bible in the Islamic State', reading from it in public in Saudi Arabia? If this is intended to be 'confirmation' for either Justinian or Henry, I'd say these are two very focussed, but different questions from the above.

Comment: @LangLangC, I've edited the question and am now more specific. Hope that helps.

Comment: The [Code of Justinian](https://droitromain.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/Anglica/codjust_Scott.htm) seems to only mention *scripture(s)* when quoting the biblical text, or talking about oaths.

Comment: Being raised a Catholic, I long ago was told that the Church did not encourage people to read the Bible - too much.  I think it was because the Church hierarchy wanted to maintain a captive audience and dole out what people should believe.  I never heard that it was forbidden to read, but maybe church leaders discouraged it enough so that people didn't get to uppity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question suffers under a couple of misapprehensions I think.

The first one is that there's a single unitary "The Bible" out there somewhere.

What we have is translations drawn from copies of older sources. These older source copies themselves, being hand copies, all have differences with each other. Which ones are "right"? Take your pick between "we don't know", and "none of them are".

Also, language translations are inherently interpretations, so anything that isn't in the older source's language should be considered a paraphrase. Or to put it in Paul's terms, we are only seeing through a mirror, darkly.

So its much more accurate to ask about specific compilers/translators Bibles. For example, possession of [Wycliffe's Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wycliffe%27s_Bible#Church_reaction_and_controversy) could get you executed in Henry IV's England. The Catholic Church also wasn't a big fan of the translation choices in the [Tynedale Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndale_Bible) which seemed to downgrade the need for organized church hierarchy. They finally hit on the idea of fighting fire with fire, and produced their own translation ([The King James Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#Considerations_for_a_new_version)) which was intentionally more biased towards authoritarian institutions like the King and the Catholic Church.

The second misapprehension is that there was a canon "Bible" from go. In fact for the first 4 centuries everyone just copied around the stories that they found most useful, and some of them said quite contradictory things to some of the others. At the end of the 4th Century the church set down a definitive "Canon", that left a lot of this stuff out. Some of it we know as apocrypha, but some of the more troublesome stuff, particularly the Gnostic Gospels, were actively suppressed. If you were a Gnostic at this time, from your perspective, yes they'd just made your "Bible" illegal to read. They'd also excommunicated your leaders though, so you might have bigger problems than reading.

Comment: [Gnosticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism) was a second and third century heresy, diametrically opposed to the [Judaizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaizers) of the first century, rejecting the Hebrew scriptures, along with other Jewish beliefs or practices; by the late third and early fourth century, the main heresies were another pair of diametrically opposed teachings, namely [Sabellianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabellianism) and [Arianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arianism); later on, Nestorianism and Monophysism formed another such pair.

Comment: I didn't know how to put it more general, and everyone is complaining it's not specific enough. While I appreciate the comment and see the reasoning. I'd like to say ANY translation or timeline or biblical cannons are welcome.

Comment: Yes we don't have the originals, yes there are translations, yes there are different cannons.
I'm expecting a partial, incomplete list of mostly European/Roman Empire instances or medieval ones, of censorship of biblical books.

Comment: @Dan: No Christian Roman Emperor or European king, regardless of denomination, ever censored any of the sixty-six canonical books, if that's what you're asking. During ancient and medieval times, espousing beliefs which ran contrary to the accepted *interpretation* of Christianity, was indeed a punishable offense (again, if that's what you're asking); see [state church of the Roman Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_church_of_the_Roman_Empire) and the [seven ecumenical councils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_seven_ecumenical_councils). And Justinian did indeed persecute heretics.

Comment: @Lucian - This is kind of exactly what I was saying. There's not really such a thing as "the ...canonical books". There's no metric standard laying under lock and key in Geneva for those "books". They are compiled based on each researcher's personal judgements of what the earliest and best copies we have are out of all the extant copies and scraps around the world, and then translated into modern languages by human beings. Kings and Popes have **totally** censored renditions of them that they didn't like for whatever reason. I even gave two examples: Wycliffe's and Tyndale's.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I believe we are talking about different things here; selecting which manuscripts, variants, and/or translations are best suited for one's purposes, versus eliminating entire books from a collection.

Comment: I believe in my childhood, the books of the Bible that Protestants use and Catholics don't  were on the prohibited list.  Does that count?

Comment: Is it worth noting that the KJV was a CofE project that, if anything, was *anti*-Catholic? (It was also not very sympathetic to the Puritans -- King James himself, remarked "No bishops, no king" foreseeing that the Puritans (who despised the CoE and Lutherans for retaining bishops) would see the king as equally dispensable. As his son Charles I might have realized if he'd kept his head.)

Comment: @MCW which books do Protestants use that Catholics don't? There are more books in the Catholic Bible than a Protestant one.

Comment: This appears misleading. It's like saying there is no "Gettysburg Access" because some of the available copies slightly vary from the other and it has been translated into different languages. The "Bible", give or take a few (less popular) books, has largely almost always been the same. The question is about if any text that we would call a "Bible" was ever prohibited from the laity. Also, what's your source for suppression of Gnostic texts? Tons of them survive - I've seen no evidence to back this up.

Comment: @arara - That would be a good analogy if the GA had been delivered before the printing press (and thus mass-producing identical copies) had been invented, and the oldest manual copy we had of it was made 200 years after it was delivered, and was only a scrap, and many of our older copies had whole passages seemingly missing, as if they'd [been inserted centuries later](http://personman.com/6-added-passages).

Comment: @T.E.D. I think it's a fine analogy, what we've got of the Bible beats anything else from the ancient world anyways. There are actually five entirely different versions of the GA. If you'd like, I can say "that's like saying there's no 'one' Aristotle". The 'insertions' you're talking about, btw, constitute less than a percent of a percent of the whole. Variation in the GA copies are much more significant.

Comment: @arara - You're free to think that, but its simply not. However, it is a rather good illustration of the problems we can have from something that's so recent you'd expect it to be definitive. It only happened about 170 years ago, we had printing presses and telegraphs, and we **still** don't know exactly what was said. Biblical manuscripts have way way more problems with errors, additions, and inconsistencies. Like multiply this by 100s. Add in that some in the early church had whole other books, and thought some of the ones we have are nonsense.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't think this conversation should go much further, but the issues you're referring to are pretty exaggerated and it's widely agreed that few of any NT teachings/theology are affected by this variation.

Comment: -1 So was there ever a ban on lay people reading the Bible, beyond a ban on specific translations? This answer doesn’t say. In fact, there were much broader bans than this answer suggests; see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_the_Bible.

Comment: It's strange that this is the accepted answer, as it does not answer the question at all. Yes, the texts of the books known as the Bible have differed in various times, regions and denomination and that is still the case today. But the differences are not as dramatic as @T.E.D. tries to make out. The question was: were laypeople ever forbidden from reading the Bible, *implying* whatever version was current in their time, region or denomination. Whether that version did or did not include Daniel 13 and 14, Tobit or Maccabees, makes very little difference to the intent of the question.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij - That's not how SE sites work. If the OQ selects an answer, then it **by definition** answered their question. That checkmark is theirs to bestow. It is possible (and sometimes reasonable) to have qualms with the question being worded in such a way that it isn't clear why this answers it, but that's a qualm with *the question*, not the answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not quite. That checkmark is indeed theirs to bestow, but it doesn't mean *by definition* that it answered their question. It means that the OP thinks that it answered their question the best out of all the answers. The OP could be wrong. I agree with Elise, most of this answer is not about bans on the Bible, and you are massively exaggerating the discrepancies in the Bible. The Gettysburg Address is a few hundred words, the New Testament is more than a hundred thousand words long.

Comment: @Nacht - Do not agree. If the question the user had was not answered, a user is not supposed to checkmark anything. If it was answered, they are supposed to checkmark the answer that was most helpful to them. The pop-up text around the checkmark supposedly makes this clear (whether it does or doesn't I'm not going to get into). Fact remains that if there's a mismatch in your mind, and the answer has a checkmark, your issue is with your understanding of the intent of the question, and the OQ is really the one person most qualified to clarify the matter for you.

Comment: I've been on SE network sites for more than a decade now, and this was something it took me quite a while to grok. At first I'd get really frustrated when I'd make a technically perfect answer, and then get passed over in favor of someone who saw through the question to what the OQ was trying to get done. But that's the game here. Ultimately, we're here to **help the people** who have the questions.

Answer (score 6):

There are different approaches to such a broad question — if anyone *wants* — to answer 'yes', which are defensible.

To address one example given in the question:

> the popular notion that the laity was forbidden to read the Bible in English under late medieval law […] misunderstands the Oxford Constitutions of 1408, which merely prohibited the making of new, unauthorised translations of the Bible.
>
> — Jonathan Reimer: "Thomas Cranmer. By Susan Wabuda. Routledge Historical Biographies, New York–Abingdon: Routledge, 2017".

Which hints at the also so called [Arundel's Constitutions](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095427318) which took on 'problems' like the [Wycliffe bible](https://kingscollections.org/exhibitions/specialcollections/bible/first-english-bible/wycliffe-bible)

If we just look for any 'secular power', then an American school board may
fit the bill quite nicely. Albeit this is somewhat a struggler over definitions in more than one way, one example might be:

— William W. Boyer: "The Bible in Wisconsin Public Schools: A Forbidden Book"
Religious Education, 55:6, p403–409, 2006.[doi](https://doi.org/10.1080/0034408600550602)

Of course, the more general approach must look at the universal church, [una sancta](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803110603806), especially in the form of what is now known as The Holy Roman Catholic church.

As closely as any match could be to what is hinted at in the question:

> We prohibit also that the laity should be permitted to have the books of the Old and New Testaments; unless anyone from the motives of devotion should wish to have the Psalter or the Breviary for divine offices or the hours of the blessed Virgin; but we most strictly forbid their having any translation of these books.
>
> — [WP: Censorship of the Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_the_Bible), with quite some more examples not reproduced here

This is a bit dependent on *which* bible was prohibited. Having a Vulgate version would be much less of a problem. But this is ultimately based on what exactly the powers that be or were would define as *heresy.* This of course started with the very first [canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_the_New_Testament_canon#Marcion_of_Sinope) — or a bible — that ever came to be in to Christianity.

[Marcion of Sinope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcion_of_Sinope) suggested that a proper bible would be without any Old Testament (thus *he* was rejecting another bible), but only consist of 'his' Lukanian-ish gospel and ten letters of Paul. While at first a very wealthy and this welcome member to the Roman fold, his ideas turned out to be seen as heretical. The obvious result was that he, his followers and his version of 'the book' were excommunicated and banned. Not so obvious was that indeed he got the money he donated to the church back in the process ;) That after their fallout the remaining Catholics weren't fond of anyone reading *that* bible seems quite evident in the fact that we have no extant copy of it.